# Purpose of shm_open() and ftruncate()?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

When we create a shared-Memory we use `shm_open()` and `ftruncate()` function. According to my information `shm_open()` create a shared-memory region. And then we use `ftruncate()` function to configure the size of shared-memory region.

Well how does `shm_open()` creates the memory region in the first place when it doesn't yet know the size? And if this is not the case and I am totally wrong, then please tell me the purpose of `shm_open()` and `ftruncate().` Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main point of `shm_open` is that you can open an **existing** memory area. However in the case that it didn't exist and you'd **create** it, `shm_open` will create a *new shared memory object* of 0 bytes, just like `open` with `O_CREAT` would create a file of 0 bytes. From [Linux manuals](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open):

> `O_CREAT`
>
> Create the shared memory object if it does not exist. The user and group ownership of the object are taken from the corresponding effective IDs of the calling process, and the object's permission bits are set according to the low-order 9 bits of mode, except that those bits set in the process file mode creation mask (see umask(2)) are cleared for the new object. A set of macro constants which can be used to define mode is listed in open(2). (Symbolic definitions of these constants can be obtained by including .)
>
> **A new shared memory object initially has zero length--the size of the object can be set using `ftruncate(2).`** The newly allocated bytes of a shared memory object are automatically initialized to 0.

(emphasis mine)

Since `shm_open` does not take the size of newly created area as an argument (it'd complicate the system call / library call to add arguments for all sorts of cases), `ftruncate()` must used to change the size of an opened shared memory area from its initial size.

---

Of course you do not have to use `ftruncate` for a shared memory segment that is already properly created and resized elsewhere. Should you want to know its size, use `fstat`. See also [`shm_overview(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)

Comment: Yep. *shm_open* follows the concept that the *creator* of the shm region determines its size, the *users* don't even need to *know* it. Otherwise you would need to have some sort of *contract* between the parties what the size should be.

Comment: "*shm_open behaves like open when creating a file*": does this mean that `shm_open` does not differ at all from `open` when creating a file, and can be replaced by it?

Comment: @ギョーム no, and fixed.