# mmap SIGBUS error and initializing the file

Tags: c, mmap

I'm trying to model a basic CPU by mmapping a 1 MiB file, corresponding to the RAM size. I want to read/write this file. Currently I'm getting a SIGBUS error with `ram[2] = 1` which I gather is from trying to mmap outside the file range. I've read that perhaps I need to fill the file with zeroes as placeholders, but I'm a bit confused as to why I have to do this, since I thought mmap would automatically set aside a memory chunk for me that would be allocated when I first touch it (as I am trying to do below with my test). What am I missing?

```
int16_t ramD;
if ( (ramD = open("ramMap.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666)) == -1)
{
    errx(EX_OSERR, "RAM could not be initialized");
}

uint8_t* ram = mmap(0, ram_bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, ramD, 0);

ram[2] = 1;
printf("%i", ram[2]);
```

Comment: what is the value of `ram_bytes`?

Comment: You didn't check if `mmap` succeeded!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it doesn't matter, sigbus will be generated when the mapping is successful.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sure, but that would be a completely different reason than if, for example, he's on a platform that whose shared memory support has been disabled.

Comment: @myaut ram_bytes is 1048576  (1 MiB)

Comment: Sidenote: If you want to model a CPU, why not simply allocating the RAM? Why the complicated way mmapping a file?

Comment: Also `int16_t ramD;` is a very strange variable type for a file descriptor. Why not just use an int?

Comment: @Olaf mmap allows me to sync the file to disk using msync after a series of processes that act on the RAM memory (file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `SIGBUS` means that you're writing outside the file. From Linux man pages [`mmap(2)`](http://www.manpages.info/linux/mmap.2.html):

> **`SIGBUS`**
>
> Attempted access to a portion of the buffer that does not correspond  to  the  file  (for  example, beyond the end of the file,
>             including the case  where  another  process  has  truncated  the
>             file).

As you create a new file, it is initially *empty*, i.e. has size of 0 bytes. You need to resize it using `ftruncate` to be at least big enough to contain the address written to (possibly rounded up to the page size). As you wanted to have a ram disk of size `ram_bytes`, then:

```
ftruncate(ramD, ram_bytes);
```

[See this answer for a longer explanation about the same mechanism, using POSIX shared memory objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056164/918959).

---

PS. `open` returns an `int`; you should use an `int`, not `int16_t`, to store the file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using posix_fallocate which ensures disk space is allocated unlike ftruncate.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_fallocate.3.html