# Accessing binary files with mmap vs fstream or fopen

Tags: c++, c, ipc, system-calls, mmap

I did not know binary files could be read with `mmap()`. I used to think `mmap()`could only be used for IPC(interprocess communication) in Linux to exchange data between unrelated process.

Can someone explain how files are read with `mmap()`? I heard it has huge advantage when binary files are randomly accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `mmap`ping a file is done the same way as it is done for the IPC or mapping anonymous memory. In the case of mapping anonymous memory the parts that have not been written to will be filled with zeroed pages on demand.

In case of a mapped file, the pages that correspond to file contents are read upon access (and upon writes too) from the file / or the buffer cache. Reading or writing outside the size of the file will result in [SIGBUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553907/mmap-sigbus-error-and-initializing-the-file/44554121#44554121). Essentially the pointer returned by `mmap` can be considered in the similar manner as the pointer returned by `malloc`, except that up to the size of mapping / up to the end-of-file bytes within the mapping are automatically read from / and possibly written to the backing file transparently.

Example:

```
fd = open("input.txt", O_RDWR, 0666);
fstat(fd, &stat_result); 
char* contents = mmap(0, stat_result->st_size,
                      PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

(error checking omitted)

After executing that you can consider `contents` as pointing to the first byte of a character array of `stat_result->st_size` characters, and you can use it just like an ordinary array, and the operating system will transparently write back the changes into the file.

---

With `mmap` the operating system will have a better view about which parts of the file should be kept in memory / buffer cache and which shouldn't.